# Application in android is closing when I do any change in the actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

This is the manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/professor"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

This is the Style :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>


<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#DC980005</item>
</style>
```

When I change the background color the application is crushed and closed!
I searched alot in the internet but no reason for the application to not open!
Please any help..

This is the logCat :

```
01-24 16:52:47.951  28973-28973/com.example.user.ascs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.user.ascs, PID: 28973
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.ascs/com.example.user.ascs.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Use LogCat to look at the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I Posted the LogCat ,I Did what they said and used Theme.AppCombat but still the same error! @CommonsWare

Comment: "I Did what they said and used Theme.AppCombat but still the same error!" -- the code in the question matches the error, showing that you are not using `Theme.AppCompat`. Here is a directory of projects that do successfully use `Theme.AppCompat`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat

Comment: Thank u alot:)
But why should I use only Theme.AppCombat?
I wanna use Theme.holo.etc.. and others!
Why the android studio is forcing me to use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the android studio is forcing me to use this?

Android Studio is not "forcing" you to do anything.

My guess is that you created a new project in Android Studio, and in there you created a new activity. The templates for such a project set up the project to use `appcompat-v7` and its `ActionBarActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc. This gives you an action bar that works back to API Level 7, whereas the native action bar only works back to API Level 11. And the `appcompat-v7` action bar resembles the Material Design action bar that is native to Android 5.0.

You do not have to use any of that. It is merely what was given to you from a template. If you do not like what is in the template, you need to change the files that were generated for you from the template. This is no different than how templates work in any other tool, whether a development tool (e.g., Web site generator) or an office productivity tool (e.g., Microsoft Word).

In this specific case, you are welcome to:

- Remove the `appcompat-v7` line from your `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file. In a typical Android Studio project, that file would be the one in your `app/` module directory.
- Change your activity to inherit from `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.
- Change your theme to not use `Theme.AppCompat`.
- Change your menu resources (`app/src/main/res/menu/*` in a typical Android Studio project) to replace any `app:` prefixes with `android:` ones (e.g., `app:showAsAction` becomes `android:showAsAction`).

Then, you will not be using `appcompat-v7` anymore. You will be using the native action bar on API Level 11+, falling back to the old-style options menu if your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 11. You will be able to have your theme inherit from one of the `Theme.Holo` series, optionally inheriting from `Theme.Material` for Android 5.0+ devices (e.g., in a `res/values-v21/styles.xml` file).

Comment: The instructions help solve the issue for me as well. Thx 
Though it's very confusing to be given a template that does not work as expected.
To top that the instructions from where this example comes from here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html are wrong as well.
Again, thanks for help, i'm sure this is all obvious when you understand how all these files ineterelate.